# How to make SQL Subqueries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, group-by

Make a list of employees whose remuneration is available from the average remuneration in their branch and display the average remuneration in the employee's branch. The list should be ordered by branch identifier.

My code looks like this but I can't add it to display the average salary in the employee ward.

```
SELECT nazwisko, wynagrodzenie, oddzial
FROM pracownicy p
WHERE wynagrodzenie> (SELECT AVG(wynagrodzenie)
FROM pracownicy
WHERE p.oddzial=oddzial);
```

However, this code displays the average wage but for all employees:

```
SELECT nazwisko,
(SELECT AVG(wynagrodzenie) FROM pracownicy
WHERE oddzial = p.oddzial) as srednia
FROM pracownicy p LEFT JOIN oddzialy z ON p. oddzial = z.oddzial;
```

Comment: update your question add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 1):

If you want to both filter with and display the average remuneration, then a `join` is a better option than a subquery.

But here, I would simply recommend window functions; you can do a window average of `wynagrodzenie` across all rows having the same `oddzial`, and then use that information for filtering and display as follows:

```
select nazwisko, wynagrodzenie, oddzial, avg_wynagrodzenie_oddzial
from (
    select p.*, avg(wynagrodzenie) over(partition by oddzial) avg_wynagrodzenie_oddzial
    from pracownicy p
) t 
where wynagrodzenie > avg_wynagrodzenie
```

Comment: Is this the only effective and fastest solution?

Comment: @xyz: I would expect this to perform better than using subqueries or joins.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @GMB woudn't you neet to add ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ? the default window is ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Should have googled it myself :)

Comment: @GabrielDurac: without an order by clause, the window function operates over the whole partition. –

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple join query for that case, so that could reduce implicit (sub query) or explicit (to be displayed) result size that come from persistent table scanning.

```
SELECT nazwisko, wynagrodzenie, p.oddzial, avg_wynagrodzenie
FROM pracownicy p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT oddzial, AVG(wynagrodzenie) as avg_wynagrodzenie
    FROM pracownicy
    GROUP BY oddzial
) t
ON p.oddizial = t.oddizial
   AND p.wynagrodzenie > t.avg_wynagrodzenie;
```